# "All, but her, " vs. "All, but she, had"

Tags: pronouns, subjects, grammatical-case

> 1. All, but **her**, had made an attempt.
> 2. All, but **she**, had made an attempt.

If *all* is the subject of the sentence, should I use a subject or object in the parenthesis statement? Why?

Is this correct way to punctuate my statement?

According to the website, *[IndiaBix](http://www.indiabix.com/verbal-ability/sentence-improvement/015014)*, the correct answer is **All, but she,**

> [image]

I have searched for an answer in these two questions, but they did not help me.

[Is "all but one" singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107973/is-all-but-one-singular-or-plural)
["All but" idiom has two meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9967/all-but-idiom-has-two-meanings)

Comment: On EL&U I think ***all*** your questions could have been pretty good, *but for* the lack of effort and research. And after being here a while, you get penalised for that. But thanks to tchrist ♦ your question has been reopened. Please, next time, explain your confusion and do a bit of Googling before asking a new question.

Comment: @Lawrence: In OP's context here, ***but = except***, so I think the [Case after 'except'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365333/case-after-except/365337) dup I linked to in my closevote is more specific.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. I can retract my close-vote but can't change it to point to yours, so I'll just leave this comment to point any future reviewers to the duplicate you found.

Comment: @FumbleFingers hmmm, I found the following title, 1968, *Whence all but he had fled*, which seems to be inspired by a line from the  poem [Casabianca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casabianca_(poem))

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Back when I was a kid we used to trot that one out with different (usually, smutty) variations on the next three lines in each verse. As best I can recall though, we got round the "questionable" grammar and dated diction of the second line in the first verse by switching to *When all **around** had fled*. You might find [this link](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sentence+all+but+he+had%22) interesting. But I can't really explain why ***he/she*** seems to work in some contexts like that, given that *Everyone except **I** went home* is so obviously "unacceptable".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see etymologynerd deleted their answer. Could have at least looked at my comment underneath the OP's question. That is, I believe the only valid example, there's also a Shakespearian line from Midsummer's Night dream containing the citation [*But what of that? Demetrius thinks not so.
He will not know what **all but he** do know.](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/msnd/page_18.html), which  thrilled me for  one or two minutes...

Comment: Basically they both stink.  And the commas don't belong there. "Everyone but her had made an attempt" is far more idiomatic.  In this case "but" is a preposition, so it takes the object form of the pronoun.  The commas greatly confuse things, as they make it unclear whether "but" is a preposition or a conjunction.